# Could not resolve placeholder after adding spring-boot-admin-starter-client dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, cron, spring-boot-admin

In my application I have method annotated with `@Scheduled(cron="${my.cron.prop}")`

I don't have `my.cron.prop` in property file and my job just don't start but application starts successfully.

But when I add dependecy:

```
compile ("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:1.5.7")
```

My application fails to start:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'reportCurrentTime': Could not resolve placeholder 'my.cron.prop' in value "${my.cron.prop}"
```

How can I fix it?

Expected behaviour - just don't start job in case of property is not provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you application did not `@EnableScheduling`, *spring-boot-admin-starter-client* does.

You could avoid this by providing a default value: see other answer

a nicer way to fix this is to use a dedicated component to launch your job when the property is available

```
@Component 
@ConditionalOnProperty( name = "my.cron.prop" )
public class Tasks {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.prop}")
    public void task() {
       /*do your suff*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You coud try something like that: `@Scheduled(cron="${my.cron.prop:0 0 0 1 1 ? 2090}")`

In that case, if the property cannot be found, Spring will use the default value that you have provided (firing in 2090 in my example).

Comment: yes, it is good workaround. But I want to find out why it happens after adding dependency